# Validating multiple files in array

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I need to validate multiple uploaded files, making sure they are of a specific type and under 2048kb. The below doesn't appear to check all files in the array 
'files' and just presumes the posted files of invalid mime type as it seems to be checking the array object and not its contents.

```
public function fileUpload(Request $request)
    {

       $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
            'files' => 'required|mimes:jpeg,jpg,png',
        ]);

        if ($validator->fails())
        {
            return response()->json(array(
                'success' => false,
                'errors' => $validator->getMessageBag()->toArray()

            ), 400);             }

}
```

Answer (score 80, accepted):

You can validate files array like any input array in **Laravel 5.2**. This feature is new in Laravel 5.2.

```
$input_data = $request->all();

$validator = Validator::make(
    $input_data, [
    'image_file.*' => 'required|mimes:jpg,jpeg,png,bmp|max:20000'
    ],[
        'image_file.*.required' => 'Please upload an image',
        'image_file.*.mimes' => 'Only jpeg,png and bmp images are allowed',
        'image_file.*.max' => 'Sorry! Maximum allowed size for an image is 20MB',
    ]
);

if ($validator->fails()) {
    // Validation error.. 
}
```

Comment: Thanks, did the trick. I am wondering if there is some shorthand way of also  making a rule where all the files in the array can't exceed say 5MB ?

Comment: change the max to `max:5000`

Comment: But would that be 5000kb per image file or for the whole array ? I am guessing per file

Comment: Yes, it will be for every single image file.

Comment: I am using laravel 5.5.42 & PHP version 7.0.30. And Custom message is not working with it. Anyone has any idea about it ?

Comment: I tried this piece of code in Laravel 6 but is not working. Something changed in Laravel 6?

Comment: If I wanted to establish a validation for the max size of the total files. Per se: 25MB.
And also wanted to say they are optional and must be files(each one)? @im_tsm

Answer (score 5):

Please try this:

```
public function fileUpload(Request $request) {
    $rules = [];
    $files = count($this->input('files')) - 1;
    foreach(range(0, $files) as $index) {
        $rules['files.' . $index] = 'required|mimes:png,jpeg,jpg,gif|max:2048';
    }

    $validator = Validator::make($request->all() , $rules);

    if ($validator->fails()) {
        return response()->json(array(
            'success' => false,
            'errors' => $validator->getMessageBag()->toArray()
        ) , 400);
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried that It's validating but not passing through $validator->passes()...we're so close

Answer (score 5):

we can also make a request and validate it.

```
    php artisan make:request SaveMultipleImages
```

here is the code for request

```
namespace App\Http\Requests;

use App\Core\Settings\Settings;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\FormRequest;

class SaveMultipleImages extends FormRequest
{
    /**
     * Determine if the user is authorized to make this request.
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    public function authorize()
    {
        return true;
    }

    /**
 * Get the validation rules that apply to the request.
 *
 * @return array
 */
    public function rules()
    {

        return ['files.*' => "mimes:jpg,png,jpeg|max:20000"];
    }
}
```

and then in controller

```
public function uploadImage(SaveMultipleImages $request) {

     dd($request->all()['files']);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this way.

```
// getting all of the post data
$files = Input::file('images');

// Making counting of uploaded images
$file_count = count($files);

// start count how many uploaded
$uploadcount = 0;

foreach($files as $file) {
    $rules = array('file' => 'required'); //'required|mimes:png,gif,jpeg,txt,pdf,doc'
    $validator = Validator::make(array('file'=> $file), $rules);
        if($validator->passes()){
            $destinationPath = 'uploads';
                $filename = $file->getClientOriginalName();
                $upload_success = $file->move($destinationPath, $filename);
                $uploadcount ++;
        }
}

if($uploadcount == $file_count){
    //uploaded successfully
}
else {
    //error occurred
}
```

Comment: I used this one. This solution is pretty good if you need to i.e. validate a certain filename or any validation that's more complex than what the validator filters can do.

Comment: life save was looking this for an hour Thanks mate