# Laravel 4.2 Upload and validate multiple images

Tags: php, laravel

I am using Lravel 4.2
I need to validate images upon the uploading

this is the form filed

```
{{ Form::file('img[]', array('class'=>'file', 'multiple', 'accept'=>'image/*')) }}
```

so this what I try

```
$files = Input::file('img');
foreach ($files as $file) {
    // validating each file.
    $rules = array('img' => 'required|image'); //'required|mimes:png,gif,jpeg,txt,pdf,doc'
    $validator = Validator::make(array('img' => $file), $rules);
    if ($validator->passes()) {
        $destinationPath = 'images/propertyImages/';
        $filename = $file->getClientOriginalName();
        $file->move($destinationPath, $filename);
    } else {
        return Redirect::back()->withInput()->withErrors($validator);
    }
}
```

But every time I upload it's back with

> The uploaded files has to be images

I am uploading already images

dump and die of `$files`

> ```
> array(3) {
>   [0]=>
>   object(Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile)#9 (7) {
>     ["test":"Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile":private]=>
>     bool(false)
>     ["originalName":"Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile":private]=>
>     string(14) "iconDoctor.png"
>     ["mimeType":"Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile":private]=>
>     string(9) "image/png"
>     ["size":"Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile":private]=>
>     int(10489)
>     ["error":"Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile":private]=>
>     int(0)
>     ["pathName":"SplFileInfo":private]=>
>     string(23) "C:\wamp\tmp\phpAF3B.tmp"
>     ["fileName":"SplFileInfo":private]=>
>     string(11) "phpAF3B.tmp"
>   }
> ```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Validating multiple files in array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38326282/validating-multiple-files-in-array)

Comment: Yes I saw it but dose it go with Laravel 4.2

Answer (score 2):

I just check your code and it is working.

#### My HTML code is following

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" class="form-horizontal form-row-sepe" id="frm_add" action="{{url('/testFunction')}}" method="post"> 
    <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">
    <input type='file' multiple name='img[]' />
    <input type="submit" class="" value="Search">
</form>
```

#### My Route is following

```
Route::any('/testFunction', 'frontend\HomeController@testFunction');
```

After doing all this I write all your code in my HomeController function and it has uploaded on the server. Maybe your FORM helper has some issues in a declaration. CHnage with my code and then check your issue.