# How can I validate array inputs in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel

This is my code:

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    try {
        $this->validate($request, [
            'activity_licenses' => 'required|image|mimes:jpeg,png,jpg,gif,svg|max:6144',
        ]);
    } catch (\ValidationException $e) {
        return [false, $e->getMessage()];
    }
    .
    .
    .
```

Actually `activity_licenses` is an array. This is the HTML:

```
<input type="file" name="activity_licenses[] />
<input type="file" name="activity_licenses[] />
```

How can I validate that? And more important that, how can I catch the reason of failure *(error message)*? Currently `$e->getMessage()` is empty on failure.

Comment: Have you checked: https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/validation#validating-arrays?

Comment: Possible duplicate question. [Solution link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38326282/validating-multiple-files-in-array?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
$input_data = $request->all();

$validator = Validator::make(
    $input_data, [
    'image_file.*' => 'required|mimes:jpg,jpeg,png,bmp|max:20000'
    ],[
        'image_file.*.required' => 'Please upload an image',
        'image_file.*.mimes' => 'Only jpeg,png and bmp images are allowed',
        'image_file.*.max' => 'Sorry! Maximum allowed size for an image is 20MB',
    ]
);

if ($validator->fails()) {
    // Validation error.. 
}
```

https://stackoverflow.com/a/38327539/3475207

Answer (score 0):

Array validation is describe in [Laravel doc](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/validation#validating-arrays) and using your case, it should be:

```
$this->validate($request, [
        'activity_licenses.*' => 'required|image|mimes:jpeg,png,jpg,gif,svg|max:6144',
    ])
```

Using the `$this->validate()` in the controller, the error messages are automatically passed to your views, and the variable `$errors` holds it. You should check: Working with Error messages in the [Laravel doc](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/validation#working-with-error-messages)

An example is (taken from the doc):

```
@if ($errors->any())
<div class="alert alert-danger">
    <ul>
        @foreach ($errors->all() as $error)
            <li>{{ $error }}</li>
        @endforeach
    </ul>
</div>
```

@endif

You may want to validate by calling the validator [manually](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/validation#manually-creating-validators) this way:

```
$validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
        'title' => 'required|unique:posts|max:255',
        'body' => 'required',
    ]);

    if ($validator->fails()) {
        return redirect('post/create')
                    ->withErrors($validator)
                    ->withInput();
    }
```

> My advice is that you should read the documentation.