# php - validate multiple file upload array in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I have a file upload input that allows multiple files to be uploaded. Right now, I am trying to find a way to validate those file uploads but not sure how to work it out.

**Code Example**

```
<input type="file" class="form-control" name="file-1649657296668-0[]" access="false" multiple="true" id="file-1649657296668-0">
```

Let's say I uploaded multiple files on this input, how do I iterate and validate each of the files in this file input and ensure that it passes the validation check? The $request variable was unable to check on each array one by one on this file upload input.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Validating multiple files in array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38326282/validating-multiple-files-in-array)

Comment: It doesn't unfortunately. I tried the method based on the link you provided, but the validation still fails. @MichaelMano

Comment: Also @cleopatez you can do front end validation also `accept="image/*"` just a side note.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EDIT: Issue solved. Apparently, on the validator check, I missed the correct format of the input file name, since the ID is automatically generated from my formBuilder. Amended my code to follow the correct format.

Input file name example: file-1649657296668-0[]

E.g:

```
validated = $request->validate([
                       'file-1649657296668-0.*' => 'max:10000|mimes:pdf,xlsx,xls,docx,doc,png,jpg,jpeg',
                    ]);
```

Make sure to not miss the asterisk for input type files with multiple attributes, or else it won't validate the rest of the files.

Answer (score 5):

You can use wildcards `*` for array items.

```html
<input type="file" name="files[]" multiple>
```

```php
request()->validate([
    'files' => 'required',
    'files.*' => 'mimes:jpeg,jpg,png'
]);
```

Comment: I tried this as well using the mimes rule, but the validation error popped up even when the file uploaded follows the right extension. @NickSdot

Comment: Laravel is checking the mime type in the content of the file. Maybe the files you test aren’t valid?https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/validation#rule-mimetypes